# Recycler View using Firestore goes to top on data changed

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have used a recyclerView with Firestore Database.

Whenever I press the like button on the feed post, the recycler view tends to go to the first post. The clicking on the like button involves 1 write and 1 update operation on a `FeedPost` object.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();    
        feedRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)fragView.findViewById(R.id.feed_recycler_view);
        setUpFeedRecyclerView();
        return fragView;
    }


    private void setUpFeedRecyclerView() {
        feedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        getFeed();

    }

    private void getFeed() {

        db.collection("XYZ")
                .orderBy("time_posted", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(100)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot snapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {

                            return;
                        }
                        List<FeedPost> feedList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : snapshots) {

                            feedList.add(doc.toObject(FeedPost.class));
                        }

                        feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(feedList);
                        feedRecyclerView.setAdapter(feedAdapter);
                        feedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
    }
```

I want to know how I can prevent the scrolling to the top of the recycler view, whenever the like button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid setting the adapter inside the event callback. Set the adapter when you're setting up the view and just update the data inside (and preferably use the correct notifyItemInserted/Removed/etc methods).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to use `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` and let it handle all these use cases.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#using-the-firestorerecycleradapter